# Vue.js add class for fade in with v-if

Tags: vue.js, tabs

I have a tab system setup with Vue.js and it works well. My only issue is that adding classes for fading in opacity doesn't seem to work with my v-if attributes:

My HTML and JS

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs-container">

    <div class="tabs">
        <a v-on:click="activetab=1" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 1</a>
        <a v-on:click="activetab=2" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 2</a>
        <a v-on:click="activetab=3" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 3 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div v-if="activetab === 1" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'tabcontent fadedIn' : '' ]">
            Content for tab one
        </div>
        <div v-if="activetab === 2"  v-bind:class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'tabcontent fadedIn' : '' ]">
            Content for tab two
        </div>
        <div v-if="activetab === 3"  v-bind:class="[ activetab === 3 ? 'tabcontent fadedIn' : '' ]">
            Content for tab three
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    el: '#tabs',
    data: { activetab: 1 },
});


</script>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.tabcontent {
  opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.tabcontent.fadedIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but something tells me I'm very close. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the html tag (`<a>` in this case), needs to first be added to the DOM (ie v-if = true), then you need to add the css class on that element which triggers the fading in.

You are causing both to happen at the same time (Inserting into DOM with a fadeIn class) and that will short-circuit the transition effect and just show it as visible.

Using vue's transition facilities (as @MatheusValenza pointed out in the comment) is one way to have the css class applied seperately after the DOM insertion.